# How can we Save an Activity state and restore it

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I'm working on an android app that contain sqlite table , and the activity that display  this activity contains setting menu and it has an option to choose how sort the table either by name, date or id and everything is working fine but when I choose to sort by name and then leave the activity it doesn't save the state that I chose (the sorting option) How can I save the state of the activity after choosing a  menuItem , Or is there an example that could help me with my problem 
thanx

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-to-save-an-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save an Android Activity state using save instance state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-to-save-an-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use shared preferences to store and retrieve your settings 
by saving the value when taping on the menuItem

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("saving", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("sort", "by name");
 editor.apply();
```

and retrieve it when activity start in onCreate

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("saving", MODE_PRIVATE); 

  String sorting= prefs.getString("sort", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
```

and then check

```
if (sorting.equals("by name")){
// do something 
}
```

i used Elenasys answer 
[Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Not the standard way to do it, check the duplicate.